# Can I move classes from an old project to a new one in Android Studio?

Tags: android, class, android-studio, android-launcher, android-studio-2.1

I want to bring over classes from the stock launcher into the one I'm developing right now. How can I do that? 
[image: Help!]

Also, thanks for all the help today.

Comment: Copy and paste them using any file explorer and then fix the package as needed

Comment: How would I do that? @Shaishav

Comment: In your IDE, right-click the `java` folder and select `Show in Explorer` for both of your projects and then copy-paste it as usual. I'm not sure why I'm typing this on SO.

Comment: @Shaishav Sorry, just a beginner. So do I just copy and paste what's in the java folder?

Comment: yeah...pretty much, the IDEs will register them as new files

Answer (score 0):

You can select the class in Android Studio and copy it from there, and then paste it into the appropriate package in your new project. This will adjust the package name automatically instead of you having to do it yourself.